# Is there a way to get a text list of all installed extensions in Visual Studio 2019/2022?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

Is there a way to get a **text list** of all installed Visual Studio 2019/2022 extensions?

I don't mean the Extensions Dialog in VS.

I want to get a list to document it in a readme file...

Comment: Do you mean a text list of all installed extensions in VS 2019/2022? If yes, then it's simple. In VS go to Help > About Microsoft Visual Studio, press Copy Info button, and paste into your readme file.

Comment: Are you looking for the list of Visual Studio Versions installed?

Comment: @PeterMacej Good answer! Only problem that there are standard extensions and modules...

Comment: @xMRi: Deleting a few lines of text shouldn't be that difficult. BTW, you should edit your question and title and mention that you want a list of EXTENSIONS in VS.

Comment: I added my comment as an answer, so that the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio, go to **Help** > **About Microsoft Visual Studio**, press **Copy Info** button, and paste the text into your readme file.

Comment: Sadly not all Addins are listed here. Sample "XALM Styler" and others.

Comment: The "XALM Styler" is there as well. But the descripton is misleading:
StylerPackage Extension   1.0
You should ask the author to fix the resources 1110 and 1112 in https://github.com/Xavalon/XamlStyler/blob/master/src/XamlStyler.Extension.Windows.Shared/VSPackage.resx